# R how to keep data in DF that hase a value in X column?

Tags: r, na

I have a DF with multiple columns of data. I want to keep all the data (rows) that have a value in column "X". Simply put i want to remove all the rows from a DF that has "NA" as a value in column "X". Right now I change the "NA" in column "X" to "0" and then remove all rows with "0" in column "X" from the DF. This is two steps. Can I do it with just one line/step?

```
DF <- DF[["X"]][is.na(DF[["X"]])] <- 0
DF <- DF[DF$X != 0,]
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `is.na` could directly be used to subset *DF*. To keep the rows without `NA` in column *X* negate the result of `is.na` using `!`.

```
DF <- DF[!is.na(DF$X),]
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. My problem was that i tried to substitute != 0 with != is.na(DF$X) and other similar  methods but it just turned my whole DF in to NA-s.